Replace first occurrence of a series of one or multiple spaces in line
I'm trying to replace the first occurrence of one or multiple spaces of lines in a file.
Reading the file line by line is no problem, but i'm having issues with the regex replacing just the first occurrence of space(s) in each line.
I manage to replace all occurences of spaces or everything up to and including the first series of spaces, but not just the first one.
Example file:
127.0.0.1 view-localhost # view localhost server
192.168.12.81     test.test.com
192.168.12.88     test.test.com

What i would like it to look like:
127.0.0.1,view-localhost # view localhost server
192.168.12.81,test.test.com
192.168.12.88,test.test.com

Replacing the first series of space or spaces with a comma in this example
Any help would be very much appreciated.

To match one or more spaces use " +". Any whitespaces: "\s+". Any horizontal whitespaces: "[\p{Zs}\t]+"

Try to replace (?m)^(\S+)[\t ]+ with $1, (demo). This is meant in (?m) multiline-mode to capture \S+ one or more non-white-space characters at ^ line-start to the first group, followed by [\t ]+ one or more tab/space and replaced with $1, what's captured by group 1 (non-white-spaces at line-start) and a comma.


Building on bobble bubble's helpful comment:
Given that your stated intent is to process the input line by line,  you can use \s+ to match any non-empty run of whitespace,
which, in line-by-line processing, is by definition intra-line whitespace (in processing of multiline strings, \s would match
"vertical" whitespace such as newlines (\n) too); if you're sure that the whitespace is comprised of spaces only,  + will do.
Thus, you can use one of the following solutions, which rely on matching the first token comprised solely of non-whitespace
characters so as to match only the first run of whitespace after it, using -replace, PowerShell's
regular-expression-based string replacement operator:
# Sample array of input lines
$lines = @(
  '127.0.0.1 view-localhost # view localhost server',
  '192.168.12.81     test.test.com',
  '192.168.12.88     test.test.com'
)

# Replace the first non-empty run of intra-line whitespace following
# at least one non-whitespace character at the start of the line with ","
$lines -replace '(?<=^\S+)\s+', ','

The above relies on a positive lookbehind assertion ((?<=...) to match any non-empty run (+) of non-whitespace characters (\S)
at the start of each input string (^) preceding the first non-empty run of (in this case intra-line) whitespace (\s+), and replaces
the latter with ,

Lookaround assertions are powerful, but - situationally - more efficient solutions may be possible.
E.g., the following - functionally equivalent - solution, performs better: it uses a capture group to
capture the non-empty run of non-whitespace characters at the start of each input string, and references
what it captured it in the substitution string, as $1, i.e. a reference to what the 1st capture group captured.
  $lines -replace '^(\S+)\s+', '$1,'

